# How to kill persistent system process in android via ADB?

Tags: android, linux, shell, linux-kernel, adb

Android process `com.android.systemui` is for showing statusbar on android.
we can kill this process and any process by adb with:

```
adb shell kill [PID]
```

and we can obtain it's PID with:

```
adb shell ps
```

and searching for PID of `com.android.systemui`

by killing this process statusbar will be hide!

but
it will start again automatically after a few seconds...!
how can we stop it and prevent to start again?

Answer (score 1):

These are critical system functions. You cant permanently kill them. Why do you want to kill the status bar?

Comment: i want to use android device as a kiosk, like a panel on a wall with only one special program running on display.

Comment: Killing the process is not a workable means of accomplishing that.  You must either work in cooperation with Android, or modify it.  As you have seen, if you try to fight it, you loose.